# Memory management using mex files with matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have a mex file that communicates with a uEye USB3 camera, captures a length of video at resolution and framerate specified by the input arguments, and exports it as a stack of .tif images. Before the mex file returns, I free the buffers I was using to store the images in, but this memory doesn't get made available to the system again, it appears to remain allocated to matlab. Further calls of mex functions appear to re-use this memory, but I can't free it to the wider system without restarting matlab. Running `clear mex` or `clear all` appear to have no influence on this, indeed `clear all` occasionally completely crashes matlab with a segmentation fault. I'm pretty sure it's not a fault with my C++ because if I rewrite the same function in straight C++ I see the memory being released as it should be.

My memory is de-allocated using

```
is_UnlockSeqBuf(hCam, nMemID, pBuffer);
is_ClearSequence (hCam);
int k=0;
while (k < frame_count){
    int fMem = is_FreeImageMem(hCam, pFrameBuffer[k], pFrame[k]);
    k++;
}
```

having previously been allocated with

```
for (int i = 0; i < frame_count;i++){
    int nAlloc = is_AllocImageMem (hCam, width,height, 24, &pFrameBuffer[i], &pFrame[i]);
    int nSeq = is_AddToSequence(hCam, pFrameBuffer[i], pFrame[i]);
    pFrame[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to release the memory without restarting matlab?

Comment: It's quite difficult to have an idea why the memory is not de-allocated without knowing how you do it. Could you post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please...

Comment: from your description, it sounds like a heap corruption error: you somewhere "step" outside the allocated arrays corrupting your heap, this prevents it from being "freed" properly and resulting with an occasional seg fault.

Comment: @ Shai I'm fairly sure I didn't step outside the arrays - the sequence I set up using the camera API is designed such that the sequence will lock itself (hence the command `is_UnluckSeqBuf()`), and the code will exit with an error if I try and step beyond what I've allocated...

Comment: Have you returned pointers to the buffers to MATLAB inside `mxArray` values using something like `mxSetData`? MATLAB takes ownership of the data allocated inside of the `mxArray` and will try to free it when the MATLAB array is deleted. Posting the code where you return the data to MATLAB will be helpful. There are functions like [mexMakeMemoryPersistent](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexmakememorypersistent.html) and [mexMakeArrayPersistent](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexmakearraypersistent.html) designed to modify lifetime management of data with MEX.

Comment: Another thing you could try if the memory issue isn't related to data ownership and you have MATLAB on Linux is to [run the MEX function in Valgrind](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/241754). It could help pinpoint the source of the error.